# Why is my JS not enabling my button?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that needs JavaScript in order for a user to submit it.  When my HTML is output, the disabled attribute is set to true.  I want my javascript to enable the button.  My JS is not enabling my button for some reason.  I get no errors in the console.

The JS:

```
(function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    buttons[0].disabled = false;
});
```

The HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="true">Next</button>
```

I have also tried DISABLED in the HTML instead of disabled="true".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to call the function, You are simply creating an anonymous function and not calling it at all.

```
(function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    buttons[0].disabled = false;
})();
//-^
```

Also the placement of this code is also important. Either Place the code at the end of body tag or use an `onload` event.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(function(){
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    buttons[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```